# restore lost php project when re-install wamp

Tags: data-recovery

today i forced to reinstall wamp on my pc. but i forgot to copy all php project on www folder on wamp and when install wamp again realize that all my php files are lose.
Can someone tell me how to restore it.

Thank you.

Comment: You will have to use undeleting software. Search on google "Kickass undelete"

Comment: may be some file recovery program, independent of PHP/wamp may help you. Or may be not, if in case those places of your harddrive have been re-written by other files. Consider using some source-code management systems like SVN, GIT, CVS, where are your codes are safe.

Comment: To add to @linuxeasy's comment, if you're using a DVCS like Git or Mercurial, make sure to push somewhere occasionally; if you accidentally delete the entire repository and you haven't pushed anywhere, it won't help you.

Comment: Are you sure you've lost the files? Installers do not usually delete existing files. Having said that, [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva) is a _free_ program which you can try if you can't get a professional data recovery software. Not as good as others but it is free.

Comment: yes. wamp removes all previous files!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try for example [O&O Diskrecovery](http://www.oo-software.com/en/products/oodiskrecovery?r=s) I have good experiance with the older O&O UnErase.

Also remember not to write any data to the harddrive e.g. don't download the software to that computer use a second one. And install the software on a second computer too!

---

I found the program from my own commend it's called [PC Inspector File Recovery](http://www.pcinspector.de/Default.htm?language=1). But this one is a little bit slow and does not work to good on Windows 7.

Very good seems to be [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva). It is fast easy to use much faster then the PC Inspector. It works also if the filesystem is damaged.

Comment: There was a second good program in orage and black but I cannot find it.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't a PHP problem. The first thing to do is: **DO NOT PUT FILES ON YOUR HARDDRIVE UNTIL YOU'VE RUN THE UNDELETE**. Now search an undelete program. There are many [here](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/filerecovery/tp/free-file-recovery-programs.htm). Run one and hope their segment wasn't overwritten.

I think you should use git, as linuxeasy already mentioned. There are many sites accepting git. Some of them don't require opensource. One of these is [pagodabox](http://pagodabox.com/), but sometimes it just refuses to connect to project due to SSL-key errors. *(But under Windows, it should work, I got problems only under Linux.)*